# Xcode console wont show error details

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been developing iOS applications for about 2 years and have never come across this before.

I recently took on a project, but for some reason whenever it crashes while I am debugging the console shows no details about the error. The code highlights with a SIGABRT or ESC_BAD_ACCESS but never tells me the details of the crash in the console (like unrecognised selector sent to instance etc.)

I've come to the conclusion this is a problem with the project settings as I test other apps with the same xCode and don't have the same problem.

I've looked all over but can't find anyone with a similar problem please help!

Comment: Is it just one crash or every crash? Try creating some errors on purpose.

Comment: at what point instance it get crashed??

Comment: This is for every crash I have experience so far - no matter what type, and no matter where in the app it crashes

Comment: What code?  The highlighted line is obtained by unwinding the stack. There are various circumstances where this is misleading - particularly when optimisation is on.

Comment: The line of code is  [self.someArray insertObject:self.objectWhichIsNowNil atIndex:rowIndex];  self.someArray still has items in it and the self.objectWhichIsNowNil is definately nil as I have manually debugged and found that this was what the problem was

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an Exception breakpoint:

1. Open the breakpoint navigator and click the + icon and add an exception breakpoint

[image] [image: Add breakpoint]

2. Add a breakpoint with the settings as shown

[image]

Comment: Yes I do have an exception breakpoint already. What is weird though is that when I enter [self performSelector:@selector(methodNameNotExistingInMyProject:) withObject:nil]; the exception is thrown and the description prints in the console. but when I enter [self.someArray insertObject:self.objectWhichIsNowNil atIndex:rowIndex];  it doesn't print the exception out at all

Comment: In your second case, is `self.someArray` definitely not `nil`? Passing a message to `nil` does nothing, including not causing errors.

Comment: yes self.someArray definately still has items in it. The self.objectWhichIsNowNil which I am passing to the method is definately nil (after some manual investigation using NSLogs I discovered that problem)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an Xcode problem. But try this two options:

1) In your VC or AppDelegate perform crash on purpose for example:

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(methodNameNotExistingInMyProject:) withObject:nil];
```

This should return you some console output

2) Are you sure you have `Debug` configuration in scheme? You may want to check it out.

[image]

Comment: What is weird though is that when I enter [self performSelector:@selector(methodNameNotExistingInMyProject:) withObject:nil]; the exception is thrown and the description prints in the console. but when I enter [self.someArray insertObject:self.objectWhichIsNowNil atIndex:rowIndex]; it doesn't print the exception out at all

Comment: just to confirm - the app is running in debug mode using LLDB