# Swift 2 - Variable initiation failed (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift, lldb

I'm just starting developing apps with Swift 2.0, and as I'm working having problem with initiating a variable with the value of a text field in my app.

this is the function I'm having problems with. It's called when a button under the text field is pressed as submit.

```
@IBAction func checkName(sender: AnyObject) { 
    guard let name : String = nameField.text else { print("Name not valid.");return}
    let checker = NameChecker()
    let result = checker.nameChecker(name)
    print(result)
}
```

this only thing this code returns on the XCode shell is "lldb". I also tried to use the debugger to figure out where I was messing up but unfortunately I found out that was harder than expected and I wasn't able to.

If you have any idea why my code is only returning "lldb" I would really appreciate is you could let me know since I've been experiencing this error quite often lately.

Comment: It sounds like you've seen in crash in the debugger LLDB is the debugger used in Xcode. Without more context we would not be able to help. Can you show of your set up code and some of the details in console after this crash.

Comment: I don't see what could cause a crash in the code.  Try and remove the connection between your IBOutlet (I assume nameField) and IBAction (checkName) and storyboard.  Reconnect them.  Product -> Clean.  Buld

Comment: I already tried to add and remove all of them and it still woudn't work. [Here](http://pastebin.com/hSgJEqgF)'s all my VieController code, I changed the names of the variables. Also if there any way I can check where the problem is from the debugger? Thanks

Comment: This might help.  If you get a meaningful error message, please update the question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468171/xcode-console-wont-show-error-details